# Creating an installer from an exe and its dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have an exe file,a .vsto file and application files. I wanted to create an installer file with these in Visual-Studio. I tried creating a new setup project (after including the necessary .csproj files) and built the solution but the exe/msi file created does not seem to work. It just gets installed but doesn't do anything.

Is the method which I followed is correct? Are there alternative methods?

Comment: I think the method sounds reasonable.  Are you saying that the installer is not installing any files?  Is is adding an entry in Control Panel/Add/Remove Programs?

Comment: it gets added to the Control Panel/Add/Remove Programs but does not execute what it should do (i am creating a plugin in MS Office- and the plugin is not loaded). Whereas, with the .exe file which I had earlier (along with .vsto and its appln files) the exe loads the plugin once installed.

Comment: Is there any difference in terms of file location and other things, between what you did first time (when it worked) and what the installer has done?

Comment: let me give you more details. I have 3 projects (say A,B,C). A is the main project and depends on B&C. B depends on C. After I publish project A, i get the files mentioned above (an exe, a .vsto and application files). Now I am trying to create an installer with the projects A,B&C and used "setup project" to create one.

Comment: Sounds fair enough, you should just be able to add project output from each of your projects to it.

Comment: okay. Something seems to work now. The msi works on my system but doesn't work on any other system (program gets installed but the plugin doesn't load onto the application)